# Prototype.js Upload and Browse not working v1.9.2.1

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript

The buttons are there, but as with 8788v2 patch they are showing on the left hand side, not the right, they are also not working. Checking in the console:

```
prototype.js:828 Uncaught ReferenceError: Uploader is not defined
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://defibshop.yoma-cloud.co.uk/js/prototype/prototype.js:612:64), <anonymous>:3:24)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://defibshop.yoma-cloud.co.uk/js/prototype/prototype.js:612:64), <anonymous>:8:7)
    at http://defibshop.yoma-cloud.co.uk/js/prototype/prototype.js:612:64
    at http://defibshop.yoma-cloud.co.uk/js/prototype/prototype.js:865:29
    at http://defibshop.yoma-cloud.co.uk/js/prototype/prototype.js:825:18
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Array.each (http://defibshop.yoma-cloud.co.uk/js/prototype/prototype.js:824:12)
    at Array.collect (http://defibshop.yoma-cloud.co.uk/js/prototype/prototype.js:864:10)
    at String.evalScripts (http://defibshop.yoma-cloud.co.uk/js/prototype/prototype.js:612:34)
    at Function.<anonymous> (http://defibshop.yoma-cloud.co.uk/js/prototype/prototype.js:391:23)
```

However I have copied the original file from the Magento version and replaced it, still not working. I have cleared the cache, reindexed and also tried a number of different browsers.

Any ideas what it could be?

8788 patch has been applied. In the console:

When loading the page, checking the console:

(index):1829 Uncaught ReferenceError: Uploader is not defined(anonymous function) @ (index):1829(anonymous function) @ (index):1834
(index):1846 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,

Comment: Have you applied SUPEE8788 ??

Comment: Yes 8788 is applied, its a strange issue I must admit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add this into Main.xml

```
<action method="addJs"><file>lib/uploader/flow.min.js</file></action>
    <action method="addJs"><file>lib/uploader/fusty-flow.js</file></action>
    <action method="addJs"><file>lib/uploader/fusty-flow-factory.js</file></action>
    <action method="addJs"><file>mage/adminhtml/uploader/instance.js</file></action>
```

Comment: Can please specify where is located your Main.xml?

Comment: where the rest of the addJs entries are.

Answer (score 2):

set js merged to `no` in `System->Configuration->Developer`

and

check below js were added or not

```
lib/uploader/flow.min.js
lib/uploader/fusty-flow.js
lib/uploader/fusty-flow-factory.js 
mage/adminhtml/uploader/instance.js
```

if those js were not included then include below js files in head and check

If those js file not present in directory then copy from the fresh magento and include this files via below code

```
<reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs"><file>lib/uploader/flow.min.js</file></action>
        <action method="addJs"><file>lib/uploader/fusty-flow.js</file></action>
        <action method="addJs"><file>lib/uploader/fusty-flow-factory.js</file></action>
        <action method="addJs"><file>mage/adminhtml/uploader/instance.js</file></action>
</reference>
```

Comment: All those JS files are there and in the correct folders. set js merged to no in System->Configuration->Developer is already done.

Comment: @RobertB please check that this files are loading in your page ??

Comment: the files are not loaded in the network tab on inspect element

Comment: @RobertB add this files in head via layout and your problem would solved

Comment: okay if I add it onto the local.xml that should work

Comment: ok add and let me know use `<default>` handler now and `local.xml` should be in `adminhtml` folder

Comment: no its not worked

Comment: those JS are loding and still the same problem ???

Comment: Yes still the same I have added into the app/design/frontend/default/template/local.xml refresh the cache, reindex etc but the buttons have not worked either, they are still on the left

Comment: Is there a specific line I need to put the reference head code?

Comment: skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/flex.swf, skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploader.swf and skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploaderSingle.swf  check this files are deleted or not

Comment: okay so the js files are not in the head. I have added them in the local.xml file, do they need to be placed anywhere else?

Comment: So I need to add them in Main.xml, any idea how I change the positions of the buttons?